# Alternatives to LSTMCELL because tensorflow_core.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running tensorflow 2.0 on fedora

I am trying to run some code which contains the line:

```
cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=hidden_units_d1,
```

This is producing the error

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

The tensorflow documentation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md) says that 'rnn' has been replaced with 'RNN API'.

What can I do to solve this issue without changing the code significantly?
How do I use the RNN API?

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to say without more context, but if it's just about running the TF1.x code in TF2 you can probably replace the line with 
`cell1 = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(...)`

This compatibility function is documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMCell?hl=en)

Note that this function is deprecated, and long term you should probably move to keras layers, documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTMCell?hl=en).

Furthermorce, information on migrating from TF1.x to TF2.0 is available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate), including an automatic conversion script.